# Run function if an alert is not showing

Tags: javascript

I've been implementing a simple CSS `<div>` overlay when a submit button is pressed on our payment forms. However, I've hit a hitch when combining with client-side JavaScript validation.

**CSS:**

```
#ukip-load {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: none;
}
#ukip-load i {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#ukip-load strong {
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ukip-load">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-5x fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>
    <br>
    <strong>Form submitting, please wait...</strong>
</div>
<button onclick="loadingSpinner();">Submit</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadingSpinner() {
    document.getElementById("ukip-load").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

**JSFiddle:**

**[This](http://jsfiddle.net/vszp9fea/)** is the basic concept, and works well for what I need.

However, we have client-side validation done through JavaScript `alert()` boxes, that pop up if certain crucial elements are missing, i.e. the amount of days for their pass is chosen, but the days they then want to attend do not match. These alerts appear at the same time as my overlay.

Is there any way to amend my function and do a check to see if there is currently an `alert()` in the window? I would then need to not run (`return false`?) my function, so they can continue to amend the form.

It will only be when the form *actually* submits that I want my overlay to appear.

Standard JavaScript only, if possible.

Comment: You can't execute code when an alert is open - it's a blocking operation

Comment: In my function that does the validation and then displays the `alert`, could I halt the execution of my code there? Or undo it's changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the loading spinner function directly, create a validation function. inside this function, using if.. else condition, you can check for the crucial elements. If the elements are missing, show the alert, else you can call the loadingSpinner function. 
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function loadingSpinner() {
      document.getElementById("ukip-load").style.display = "block";
   }
   function validate(){
   // write validation code here.   
     if(isValid){
        alert("please fill correct details");
     }
     else{
        loadingSpinner();
     }
   }
```

and inside the body you should have:

```
<button onclick="validate();">Submit</button>
```

what this does is separate your validation and your submit code. so at a time, you will either have an alert or the function will get submitted.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript `alert` dialogs are synchronous. They run on the main thread, so whilst an alert is open you **can't** have any code running.

If you really need to detect whether an alert is open, you'll need to use a custom HTML dialog. You'll also get the added bonus of styling and custom behaviour.